# CSS Colors not loading

Tags: html, css, pdf, google-apps-script

I am generating a pdf from an [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output).  CSS colors such as background colors and text colors do not appear (other styling looks like it is applied). Here is some of my code:

```
function createPDFReceipt(formRes){
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('nameOfFile'),
      date = new Date(),
      pdfFile;



  template.name = formRes.name;
  template.email = formRes.email;
  template.payment = formRes.method;
  template.deposit = formRes.deposit;

  pdfFile = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob(template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).getContent(), MimeType.HTML, 'receipt.html').getAs(MimeType.PDF).setName('pdfReceipt.pdf'));

}
```

When I log the evaluated HTML file, the style tags look 100% correct.

Here is some of my HTML and CSS to get an idea of the layout:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Receipt</title>

<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css"> -->

   <?!= include('stylesheet'); ?>

</head>
<body>

<div class='info'>
    <h1></h1>
    <h4></h4>
</div>

<div class='info'>
    <div id='receipt-info'>
        Receipt No.     <br>
        Date: <?= date ?>
    </div>

    <div id='billing-info'>
        Bill To:<br>
        Name: <?= name ?> <br>
        Email: <?= email ?><br>
    </div>

</div>
...

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

body {
  width: 900px;
  margin: auto;
}

#logo {
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table th {
    background: #404040;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

table th,td {
  border: 1px solid #404040;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

table.small th {
    width: 40%;
}

table.small tr:last-child {
    background: #ECECEC;
}

.info {
    width: 85%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#receipt-info {
  width: 40%;
  font-size: 16px;
  float: left;
}

#billing-info {
    width: 40%;
    font-size: 16px;
    float:right;

}

.table {
    clear: both;
    margin-bottom: 30px
}


#sub-table {
    float:right;
    margin-bottom: 175px;
}

footer {
    clear: both;
}

#center-span {
    /*text-align: center;*/
    position: relative;

}

#last-line {
    display: inline-block;
    /*text-align: center;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
}

</style>
```

I tried using rgb, hex, and named colors "black", "gray", etc.  Nothing worked and I can't seem to get any coloring in my PDF file.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Few Suggestions:

1. It's always better to "inline" your CSS to HTML tags when you are generating a PDF.
2. Always use full CSS property to get best result in Generating PDF. 
   For example, to assign a background color:

**What you are using:**

```
background: #ECECEC;
```

**Use this instead:**

```
background-color: #ECECEC;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the input! Unnfortunately none of these suggestions worked.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like tool can't render css class

```
table.small tr:last-child
```

try to change it to seprate class for example

```
.last-child {
 background: #ECECEC;
}
```

Or just use inline style on last td

```
<td style="background: #ECECEC;">Text</td>
```